# Angular Material Autocomplete component is not displaying the items after updating angular/material package to latest version

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, webpack-2

Angular Material Autocomplete component is not displaying the items after updating angular/material package to latest version

```
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11" before it works fine for beta.10 version.
```

**.html**

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input placeholder="Pick one"  matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Simple autocomplete
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-simple-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-simple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-simple-example.css']
})
export class AutocompleteSimpleExample {

  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  options = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
   ];

}
```

Comment: Maybe something specific to your setup? It's working here https://plnkr.co/edit/vEyj1uy52oyldcF4SVMU?p=preview

Comment: Show your `AppModule`.

Comment: @WillHowell the autocomplete works fine.The error is due to "ngx-perfect-scrollbar" latest version. If i remove "ngx-perfect-scrollbar" it works fine.

Comment: @Edric the autocomplete works fine.The error is due to "ngx-perfect-scrollbar" latest version. If i remove "ngx-perfect-scrollbar" it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this first, for you to be able to use `mat-` prefix. Visit this link for more info.
https://github.com/angular/material-prefix-updater#after-running-the-tool

```ts
import {MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE, useValue: true},
    // ...
  ],
})
export class MyModule { }
```

I tested your snippet using beta.11, the compiler throws an error in `mat-form-field`, `matAutoComplete`, `mat-autocomplete`, `mat-option`, only `matInput` compiles without errors. The alternative snippet below compiles without errors.

**C1**

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input placeholder="Pick one" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [mdAutocomplete]="auto">
    <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
      <md-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </md-option>
    </md-autocomplete>
  </md-form-field>
</form>
```

I tested your snippet using `MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE` and it works fine. If you don't want to use material compatibility mode try using snippet **C1**. Visit this link for more info on how to implement material compatibility mode to use `mat-` prefix without errors. https://github.com/angular/material-prefix-updater#after-running-the-tool

Comment: the autocomplete works fine.The error is due to "ngx-perfect-scrollbar" latest version. If i remove "ngx-perfect-scrollbar" it works fine